# How can I securely store a Google Analytics GA4 credentials.json file in Azure Functions?

Tags: python, azure-functions, google-analytics-api

I'm creating an Azure Function in Python using the google-analytics-data client library to download google analytics data every month.  The instructions on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries require the API credentials to exist locally in a file called credentials.json.  When I deploy that to Azure Functions, will that exist in plain text?  Is there any way to encrypt it?

Seems like I should be able to pass parameters in BetaAnalyticsDataClient() instead of using a file, but https://googleapis.dev/python/analyticsdata/latest/data_v1beta/beta_analytics_data.html looks like it wants a token from an OAuth handshake, not the credentials in credentials.json.

What I've found so far in my research:

- documentation for BetaAnalyticsData:  https://googleapis.dev/python/analyticsdata/latest/data_v1beta/beta_analytics_data.html
- definition of the Credentials class:  https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth.credentials.html#google.auth.credentials.Credentials
- documentation for not using the client library: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4#not_using_a_client_library

It's not a must to use the google-analytics-data client library, just seems like it would be a lot easier.  What's the best way to securely authenticate with the GA4 API from Azure Functions?

Comment: You can add the Google API credentials in your local.settings.json file in your function, The local.settings.json file will be part of git ignore so it will not be version controlled from your code.

Comment: Just deployed my code to Azure Functions and confirmed that the credentials file is deployed in plain text along with the actual code.  Has anybody out there connected to the GA4 API from Azure in a more secure way?

Comment: Sorry @SiddheshDesai, I missed your comment from before.  If I put the credentials in local.settings.json, how do I get a token for BetaAnalyticsDataClient() ?  By default, BetaAnalyticsDataClient looks for a locally installed file.  Seems like I should be able to do something like BetaAnalyticsDataClient(private_key=os.getenv('private_key')), but that errors out.

Comment: did you try os.environ["<your setting with secrets>"] or os.getenv("<your setting with secret>") in your function code to get the secret from local.settings.json? Example def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    connectionstring = os.environ["connectionstring"]
    conn = pyodbc.connect(connectionstring)
    cursor = conn.cursor() where I have connectionstring saved in my local.settings.json as "connectionstring" : "<string>"

Comment: This is for local, You can also save your secrets or credentials in Azure key vault and import those secrets in your function code refer here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606790/read-azure-keyvault-secret-from-function-app by krishg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments, @SiddheshDesai!  Your answer turns out to be half of the solution.  Step 1 is to store the entire contents of credentials.json as a single variable in local.settings.json or Azure key vault.  Step 2, as documented on https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files, is to use service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info to generate a Credentials object that can be passed to BetaAnalyticsDataClient.
My local.settings.json looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",    
    "ga4_credentials_json": "{\"type\": \"service_account\",\"project_id\": \" <etc...>
  }
}
```

And here's my working code to declare the client:

```
    json_acct_info = json.loads(os.getenv('ga4_credentials_json'))
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
        json_acct_info)
    scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'])

    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient(credentials=scoped_credentials)
```

Then you just define your request and response = client.run_report(request) !  Life is good.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Google API analytics Credentials.json and added it to my Azure Functions local.settings.json like below:-

**My local.settings.json:-**

```json
{

"IsEncrypted": false,

"Values": {

"AzureWebJobsStorage": "",

"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",

"type": "service_account",

"project_id": "quickstart-xxx3603076",

"private_key_id": "xxxxxxxeea5f0d7dc679d23af2160fb0ae4c",

"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\<private-key>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",

"client_email": "starting-account-xxxf9k2gxzg@quickstart-xxx03603076.iam.gserviceaccount.com",

"client_id": "xxxx556667352042599",

"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",

"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",

"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",

"client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/starting-account-xxxx0quickstart-xxxx3603076.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

}
```

Now, I have called the above private_key in my function code by using this code block:- `os.environ["private_key"]`

**Called the private_key in my init.py code like below:-**

```py
credentials = os.environ["private_key"]

print(credentials)
```

**Private key got logged in the Output:-**

[image]

The above method with local.settings.json will work only for Local Azure Function, As while deploying your function from local to Azure Portal the local.settings.json file is gitignored and is not a part of runtime.

So, In order to store secrets or settings in Azure Functions in Portal > You can add the same credentials.json file values in Application settings of Function app like below:-

***I selected my Azure Function > Configuration > New application settings > Add the key and value where key is your private_key and value is the private key value, Refer below:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

**An alternative is to save your credentials in Azure Key vault and call it in your Azure Function app, Refer this [Document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simplifying-security-for-serverless-and-web-apps-with-azure-functions-and-app-service/)**