# How to use an oAuth credential .json file in a GCP Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

What is the best approach to making a [runReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#specify_a_data_source) in a Google Cloud function?

There was a question about using it in Azure: [How can I securely store a Google Analytics GA4 credentials.json file in Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041302/how-can-i-securely-store-a-google-analytics-ga4-credentials-json-file-in-azure-f), but I’d like a way to implement this in Google Cloud.

Comment: probably using a service account if you can

Comment: You should be able to use the runtime service account of the cloud functions to achieve that

Comment: That didn't work - the service account does not have access to the GA property. I've also tried generating an access token to make an OAuth credential as described here: https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/user-guide.html#user-credentials. I get a "401 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential" response. Passing the access token directly into BetaAnalyticsDataClient() as credential, I get: "503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'"